# In what ways can I sanitize XSLT input?

Tags: c#, xslt

I have c# code that is reading XSLT file contents stored in an app.config that exists on the server. Loading those contents with XslCompiledTransform.Load(), is showing in HP Fortify as a High vulnerability for XSLT Injection.

In what way can I validate the input coming from the app.config so that it would pass the scan without vulnerability?

```cs
XslCompiledTransform xslDoc = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslDoc.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailxslt"]);
```

Preferrably I would like a way to run this through some sort of sanitizer, like the HtmlSanitization library used for HTML validation. Unsure if something like that exists, I havent found it if so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <style type="text/css">
          body {  font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif'; font-size: 11pt; background-color: white; color: black; }
          td { font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif'; font-size: 11pt; background-color: white; color: black; }
          p { margin-top: 8pt; margin-bottom: 8pt; }
          p + p { margin-top: 8pt; margin-bottom: 8pt; }
          blockquote { font-style: italic; margin-top: 6pt; margin-bottom: 6pt; margin-left: 12pt; }
          blockquote + blockquote { font-style: italic; margin-top: 6pt; margin-bottom: 6pt; margin-left: 12pt; }
          .Footer { font-size: 7pt; }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>

              <p>
                Some text:
              </p>

              <p>
                <xsl:element name="a">
                  <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/Root/FileUrl"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/Root/FileUrl"/>
                </xsl:element>
                </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If your config on the server is compromized, you probably have bigger problems. Otherwise, see [XSLT Security Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-security-considerations).

Comment: That is the argument I made to our security folks :) seems to be falling on deaf ears. Regardless, I appreciate the link.

Comment: It is a rather dubious argument to begin with, similar to saying that you may not blindly trust a dll that you are linked to, and must provide a way to cleanse it on the fly from potential malicious code. Yes, dll hijacking is a thing, but the way to protect from it is to make sure your dll location is secure, not to implement an antimalware engine in each program that loads a dll. (And you can't use a shared engine across several programs, because then the engine would reside in a dll, and we know what happens when you try to load a dll!)

Comment: could you put in the XSLT so we can see what HP Fortify sees as a high vulnerability?

Comment: The XSLT itself isn't what is causing the vulnerability, it could be anything. The vulnerability is the source of the XSLT itself coming from a insecure location.

I went ahead and added it, just cause.